# XCOM EW: Effect of Ignoring UFO Crashes?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown, xcom-enemy-within

I know that ignoring UFOs will result in a higher panic rate.

But what if I shoot down a UFO and ignore it? Will it also result in a higher panic rate?

Note: NOT using Long War, a.k.a., "EW Vanilla".

Comment: I read the title of the question and immediately ignored it as a "self-evidently, you don't do that." But... I don't actually know what the consequence would be. The game probably assumes you'll know it's a bad idea; but whether you act on that or not is outside my knowledge. I rate this a +1 question.

Comment: Here's a hypothetical situation: My strong-willed soldiers are all injured, leaving a bunch of low-level (or low-willed) soldiers... and this UFO has Sectoid Commanders (by delaying the Hyperwave Relay, you can get a bunch of UFOs that way)... and I prefer to wait until several strong-willed soldiers are fit enough for duty.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I looked around on a couple of other forums and found the following

[GameFaqs](https://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/655782-xcom-enemy-unknown/64396237)

> I ignored a few shot down ufo and didn't get any negative panic hits.

[2K-forums](https://forums.2k.com/showthread.php?140821-Ignoring-Crashed-Ships)

> You didn't lose any points in OG from a crashed ship, you just didn't gain any more points. Just shooting the ship down gives you points and keeps the aliens from getting a complete mission, so they don't get points.
>
> In OG, once I had things settled (month 2-3) I never sent a skyranger
>   to a crashed ship. They usually didn't have a good power core, so
>   there was really no point in going. I only assaulted supply-ships and
>   infiltration missions that were landed.

Answer (score 4):

I have just tested this.

Shot a UFO down over the USA and then did not send a Skyranger to the downed ship.

1. There was no effect on the USA's panic level.
2. It did not negatively impact my end of month Council Report.